# How to install Skype for Business via Wine?

Tags: 18.04, windows, wine, skype

I just wanted to install the [Skype for Business](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3139711/how-to-install-the-skype-for-business-basic-stand-alone-client?WT.mc_id=eml_CXM_EN-US_X_Skype4Business_SkypeApp_Download_EN-US_062019) Windows application using wine. But somehow the installer crashes all the time. Not sure if this has something to do with the fact that it seems that this .exe would just download all the needed files first. 
Is here a proper way to install Skype for business on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Have you tried downloading Skype from the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: Yes but it seems not to be same thing. Skype and Skype for Business are two different services which oddly use different apps as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 alternative options I am aware of.

One is to use https://www.tel.red/linux.php Sky.  The free version lets you screen share for up to 2 minutes, same for voice and video.  It's a bit of a pain if you need it for more than that without paying.

There is also the SIPE plugin for Pidgin if all you want to do is chat.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Do you know if SIPE handles videochat as well?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: sky is usually crashing after one/two minutes on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

That's the way Microsoft designed Skype for Business, to use shortcuts and programming tricks instead of documented system calls which WINE can handle. The WINE website [documents how Skype for Business does not work under WINE](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=18951), but a [commercial alternative is available for Linux.](https://www.tel.red/linux.php)

Comment: Thanks. That sounds actually so that Microsoft does not want you to use Skype for Business other than on Windows. 
However, will need to find and alternative or just boot into Windows for using it. Let's hope they offer a real web service soon. The commercial option is nice, but I use it not often enough that I see the need of paying.

Comment: Their attitude is changing, they just released Teams for Linux which is sort of their own competitor to Skype/Lync.  You could also put Windows in VirtualBox and run your MS apps that way.

Comment: On the note of finding something else, I had great success so far by using https://whereby.com .. It is browser based, can share screen and the free version has up to 4 people in a chatroom at once. If I am not mistaking I think it is also encrypted (They say 'secure conversations'). As well as your 'guests' won't need a login.